# How to replace a value in a column by the values of multiple dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

In my dataframe, I have multiple columns whose values I would like to replace into one column. For instance, I would like the NaN values in MEDICATIONS: columns to be replaced by a value if it exists in any other column except MEDICATION:

**Input:**

[image: Input]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

`

df['MEDICATIONS'].combine_first(df["Rest of the columns besides MEDICATIONS:"])

`

Link of the dataset:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cyZ_OWrGNvJyc8ZPNFVe543UAI9snHDT/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data - data.csv')
del df['Unnamed: 0']
df['Combined_Meds'] = df.astype(str).values.sum(axis=1)
df['Combined_Meds'] = df['Combined_Meds'].str.replace('nan', '', regex=False)
cols = list(df.columns)
cols = [cols[-1]] + cols[:-1]
df = df[cols]
df.sample(10)
```